# Customized change password page is not displaying in force.com site which is enabled for the customer portal

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, customer-portal

I am using Custom Change Password page for Force.com site.

For that site we enabled Customer portal.

And we are using High volume customer Portal licenses for the User.

Once we click on forgot password button and retrieve a temp password through email.

and enter the username and temp password in login page it is redirecting to the below url:-

/_ui/system/security/ChangePassword but it is not showing my custom change password page even

though i changed the page name in Force.com site Login Settings Change Password Column.

Comment: Can you post the full URL of your site?